# Chrome extension API / Firefox addon API for accessing all site data

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Is there an API to access all site data on all domains from a chrome extension (or firefox addin)?

Full story: I want to create a pseudo profile switcher, as an alternative to google's Google's "multiple sign-in". It will basically help user to switch between profiles that are created inside my extension. Right now, it is only a cookie-switcher because it can only access cookies (just like this extension: [Swap My Cookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/swap-my-cookies/dffhipnliikkblkhpjapbecpmoilcama?hl=en)).

For creating a new profile (inside my extension) it saves all cookies in JSON format in filesystem and then deletes all cookies in browser, just like chrome's new profile. To switch between two profiles, it saves current cookies, clears cookies, and loads cookies for target profile. Note that I am not accessing chrome's actual profiles at all, and I am certainly not reading cookies from chrome's other profiles. This is just a pseudo profile switcher. Many websites are not working as they should work, because these websites store more things than just cookies. Is there a way to access all site data, and not just cookies? I have been working with chromium so far, but for this I am ready to switch to firefox or any other browser.

Following is picture of url `chrome://settings/cookies` after clearing all cookies using chrome extension API, how do I access the rest of data?

[Image showing site data other than cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUOG2.png)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a pseudo profile switcher

For Firefox there is a [per-tab container API](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1191418) under development which may pretty much provide what you want.

Comment: This is so awesome! Apart from my use, this is a really wonderful idea, it will stop tracking cookies from so many third party websites. For example: pretty much any website that has a fb like button, will not know where else I have been! Unfortunately I am not able to up vote right now.